# App crashes every time a SharedPreference gets requested

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I want to store a int for 2 activities, in the first it gets loaded and in in the other one stored (and loaded to compare if its still the same).

Activity A:

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Pref", 0);
int score = preferences.getInt("Highscore", 0);
textView.setText(Integer.toString(score));
```

Activity B (in the onPause() part):

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Pref", 0);
int pref_score = preferences.getInt("Highscore", 0);

if (new_score > pref_score) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("Highscore", gameView.getScore());
    editor.commit();
}
```

When I run the app it crashes immediately. Activity A gets called at first, it may be a problem that there is nothing stored so far?
If I comment it out in Activity A it works until the onPause() function in B gets called (Home Button).

**Edit**
Changed all to int, still crashing [logcat](https://pastebin.com/raw/qUwcTmT4)

Comment: What is the logcat message ?

Comment: @OmarAlfak maybe this line is interesting?  10-01 22:48:34.928 513-513/? I/Gobi: vendor/qcom/proprietary/RIDL/RIDLClient/MainCore.cpp:1324: Failed to get TransState, rc

Comment: Are you sure this is really where the crash occurrs ?

Comment: If I comment the parts out it forks fine, in the emulator as well as on my phone

Comment: I was talking about the logcat message. You should look for something like "Exception"

Comment: Oh, yeah I found sth when i started the app on my phone: [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/UM1yAt60)

Comment: There is one interesting part: "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:242)" Where is there a cast? is it the wrong function to load the saved int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using "putString", and "getInt".
So you save it as a String, but try and get it as an Integer. So it tries to cast the String to an Int, thus the ClassCastException.

You have to save and get it as the same type.

Comment: fixed that one, it still chrashes : [logcat](https://pastebin.com/raw/qUwcTmT4). Line 31 (where the cast error is): int score = preferences.getInt("Highscore", 0);

Comment: Literally uninstall the app and reinstall it, that will remove whatever leftover SharedPreferences you have saved (you probably still have a String saved in "Highscore" field)

Comment: Please do upvote and accept my answer if it helped you then :)

Answer (score 1):

In `Activity A` you use `preferences.getInt()` while in `Activity B` you use `preferences.edit().putString()`.

After you've fixed this, you will have to uninstall/reinstall your app or override the `String` value contained in your `SharedPreference` or it will still crash when you try to get it through `getInt()`.